# Kendo Menu Direction

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-menu

Is it possible to set Kendo menu direction to auto so that it can open in any direction according to available space?

My issue is, I have a Kendo menu at the end of the page, when user tries to open kendo menu it always opens in down position, and when user tries to scroll page to see all the option, it starts flickering and then user has to refresh the screen again.

=> ASP.NET MVC application , Javascript

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I have found similar topic at https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/1317 but its related to angular js

Comment: Seems to work ok [here](http://dojo.telerik.com/AToxe/2) with default applied. Can you provide a demo of the issue?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. Have you found a solution?